# how to call an url in django view function

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to execute one of the url of urls.py with urllib in django view function.  After execution i got error like

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 411: Length Required
```

Is this possible to execute url with urllib inside django view function.

```
@login_required(login_url='http://domain/user/login?destination=apps/member/change_password')
def change_password(request):
    '''Form for user to change their password'''
    form = SetPasswordForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        ob = urllib.request.urlopen(url='http://domain/login/', data=request)
        messages.success(request, 'Your password has been succesfully updated!')
        return redirect('hq:profile')

    return render(request, 'registration/password_change_form.html',
        {'form': form})
```

when i execute urllib

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but keep in mind, that the time of that request will add up to your loading time.

If you do that from within the same django system you should think, if there would be a better solution.

In your case it may eventually use:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

authenticate(username, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by modifying as below.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

@login_required(login_url='http://domain/user/login?destination=apps/member/change_password')
def change_password(request):
    '''Form for user to change their password'''
    form = SetPasswordForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        user.backend = "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"

        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, 'Your password has been succesfully updated!')
        return redirect('hq:profile')

    return render(request, 'registration/password_change_form.html',
        {'form': form})
```